# Running a Python script outside of Django

Tags: python, django

I have a script which uses the Django ORM features, amongst other external libraries, that I want to run outside of Django (that is, executed from the command-line).

Edit: At the moment, I can launch it by navigating to a URL...

How do I setup the environment for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing Python script from Django shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853649/executing-python-script-from-django-shell)

Comment: One of the cleanest solutions is the one provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39724171/4454597

Answer (score 43):

The easiest way to do this is to set up your script as a `manage.py` subcommand. It's quite easy to do:

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand, make_option

class Command(NoArgsCommand):

    help = "Whatever you want to print here"

    option_list = NoArgsCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--verbose', action='store_true'),
    )

    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        ... call your script here ...
```

Put this in a file, in any of your apps under management/commands/yourcommand.py (with empty `__init__.py` files in each) and now you can call your script with `./manage.py yourcommand`.

If you're using Django 1.10 or greater NoArgsCommand has been deprecated. Use BaseCommand instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45172236/6022521

Comment: This is the option that I use, assuming the command is related to your project.

Comment: I get the error "NameError: name 'make_option' is not defined" when running this - is something missing?

Comment: You probably need `from optparse import make_option` at the top.

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but nobody seems to have pointed to the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: `NoArgsCommand` is deprecated since Django 1.10. Use `BaceCommand` in stead. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45172236/6022521

Answer (score 21):

```
from <Project path>          import settings          #your project settings file
from django.core.management  import setup_environ     #environment setup function

setup_environ(settings)

#Rest of your django imports and code go here
```

Comment: Unfortunately this method does not work if you use a script in \app1\ and need to use files from \app2\ unless you place it in the project root.

Comment: I think it should be "import setup_environ" instead of "import setup_environment"

Comment: This was deprecated in Django 1.4...long ago.

Comment: @mlissner is there a replacement?

Answer (score 14):

All you need is importable settings and properly set python path. In the most raw form this can be done by setting up appropriate environment variables, like:

```
$ DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings PYTHONPATH=$HOME/djangoprojects python myscript.py
```

There are other ways, like calling `settings.configure()` and already mentioned `setup_environ()` described by James Bennett in [some blog post](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/).

Answer (score 13):

Use `runscript` from [django-extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/runscript.html): `python manage.py runscript <my_script>`

In order to do this, you need to:

1. `pip install django-extensions`
2. Create a directory called `scripts`. This can be located in your root directory, or in a specific app.
3. Initialize the directory with a blank init file:

   `touch scripts/__init__.py`
4. Place your script in this directory, and include a `run()` function. Example:

   ```
   #hello.py

   def hello():
       return "Hello, World"

   def run():
       print hello()
   ```
5. Run the script with `python manage.py runscript hello`

Refer to [docs](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/runscript.html) and [helpful blog post](http://blog.brendel.com/2012/01/how-to-use-djangextensions-runscript.html) for more details.

Answer (score 11):

**Note** that the suggestions around importing settings and using setup_environ have been deprecated with Django 1.4.

There's a thread on the Django Github describing [why this was done](https://github.com/django/django/commit/38f1fe3b35).

There are still some other options out there but many of them seem hackish to me.  My preferred method is often to include the scripted function as an [extended command of manage.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Answer (score 2):

I like to add the following command to my projects:

`myproject/management/commands/run-script.py`:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

import imp
import sys


class Command(BaseCommand):

    help = """Run a non-django script with django settings."""
    args = "<path_to_script.py> [<script_args>...]"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if len(args) == 0:
            raise CommandError("Path to script to run is required")
        sys.argv = list(args)
        imp.load_source("__main__", args[0])
```

Then, I can run custom scripts, e.g:

```
./manage.py run-script /path/to/myscript.py --opt=value arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple way:

```sh
$ python manage.py shell -c 'import runpy; runpy.run_path("scripts/script_to_run.py")'
```

where *scripts/script_to_run.py* is the desired script to run!

you can create a bash script called "*runscript.py*":

```sh
#!/bin/bash
python manage.py shell -c 'import runpy; runpy.run_path("'$1'")'
```

then run:

```sh
$ runscript.py scripts/script_to_run.py
```