# Running a standalone script doing a model query in Django with `settings/dev.py` instead of `settings.py`

Tags: python, django, django-settings

Note the `settings/dev.py` instead of one `settings.py` file and the `script.py` in `my_app` in the following Django(1.4.3) project:

```
.
├── my_project
│   ├── my_app
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   └── script.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── dev.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── prod.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── requirements.txt
```

When I only had **one `settings.py` file in place of the *settings folder* I was able to run the following script without any errors**:

**script.py:**

```
###################################################################
# set up for making it possible to run a model query from my script. 
###################################################################
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)))
from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings
setup_environ(settings)
####################################################################  
from my_app.models import MyModel

all_entries = MyModel.objects.all()
```

Btw, I got that from the second approach in [this article](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/), my setup is a few lines longer because my `script.py` is in the `my_app` folder instead of directly under the `my_project` folder.

Because I am **now using `settings/dev.py instead` of `settings.py` I changed the last two lines of my setup in my script** to the following:

```
import settings.dev
import setup_environ(settings.dev)
```

But when I **run my script now** I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 12, in <module>
    all_entries = MyModel.objects.all()
  File "/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 131, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 358, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 624, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 642, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1250, in add_q
    can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
  File "/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1122, in add_filter
    process_extras=process_extras)
  File "/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1304, in setup_joins
    field, model, direct, m2m = opts.get_field_by_name(name)
  File "/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 311, in get_field_by_name
    cache = self.init_name_map()
  File "/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 341, in init_name_map
    for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():
  File "/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 429, in get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
    cache = self._fill_related_many_to_many_cache()
  File "/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 443, in _fill_related_many_to_many_cache
    for klass in get_models(only_installed=False):
  File "/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 181, in get_models
    self._populate()
  File "/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 86, in load_app
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named my_project.my_app
```

Why is this error occurring? **How can I run my script in Django with `settings/dev.py` instead of `settings.py`?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're looking to just run a script in the django environment, then the simplest way to accomplish this is to create a `./manage.py` subcommand, like this

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from my_app.models import MyModel

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'runs your code in the django environment'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        all_entries = MyModel.objects.all()
        for entry in all_entries:
            self.stdout.write('entry "%s"' % entry)
```

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) are quite helpful with explaining this.

However, you can specify a settings file to run with using

```
$ django-admin.py runserver --settings=settings.dev
```

which will run the test server using the settings in `dev` however, I fear your problems are more deep seated than simply that. I wouldn't recommend ever changing the `manage.py` file as this can lead to inconsistencies and future headaches.

Note also that `dev.py` should be a complete settings file if you are to do this. I would personally recommend a structure like this:

```
|-settings
|    |- __init__.py
|    |- base.py
|    |- dev.py
|    |- prod.py
```

and keep all the general settings in your `base.py` and change the first line of your `dev.py` etc to something like

```
# settings/dev.py
from .base import *

DEBUG = True
...
```

#### EDIT

If you're just looking to test things out, why not try

```
$ ./manage.py shell
```

or with your dev settings

```
$ django-admin.py shell --settings=settings.dev
```

as this will set all the OS environment variables, `settings.py` for you, and then you can test / debug with

```
>>> from my_app.models import MyModel
>>> all_entries = MyModel.objects.all()
>>> for entry in all_entries:
...   print entry
```

Comment: I used `from .common import *` in `dev.py` and it still produces the same error(btw my structure was already as you suggested, I just wanted the problem to be presented as simple as possible). 
I also ran the script with a new virtual environment and the same error occurred.
Doing a query from `python manage.py shell --settings=my_project.settings.dev` works perfectly fine.

Comment: I can't see a `common` module in your dir structure - is that a typo?

Comment: My mistake, it's named `common.py` in my real project, according to your example It's the same as `base.py`. If I remove `settings_environ` I get `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.` Btw my `settings.DATABASES` is identical to the one in my old `settings.py` file, which ran without a problem.

Comment: How are you running your script and what is its purpose? To avoid the `settings` difficulties, run everything from `./manage.py` - hence my recommendation to use the shell. If you're writing a script that needs to be executed by the django instance, use a `manage.py` [subcommand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310495/running-a-python-script-outside-of-django). If that's overkill, go back to debugging in the shell - it's much easier.

Comment: Thanks, Just got the same answer from Irc. I think using custom django-admin.py commands is the least messy solution. Could you include this in your answer so I can accept it?