# Django Standalone Script

Tags: python, django

I am trying to access my Django (v1.10) app DB from another python script and having some trouble doing so.

This is my file and folder structure:

```
store
 store
   __init.py__
   settings.py
   urls.py
   wsgi.py
 store_app
   __init.py__
   admin.py
   apps.py
   models.py
   ...
 db.sqlite3
 manage.py

other_script.py
```

In accordance with [Django's documentations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) my `other_script.py` looks like this:

```
import django
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(DEBUG=True)
django.setup()

from store.store_app.models import MyModel
```

But it generates a runtime error:

```
RunTimeError: Model class store.store_app.models.MyModel doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I should note that my `INSTALLED_APPS` list contains `store_app` as its last element.

If instead I try to pass a config like this:

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
from store.store_app.apps import StoreAppConfig

settings.configure(StoreAppConfig, DEBUG=True)
django.setup()

from store.store_app.models import MyModel
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: type object 'StoreAppConfig has no attribute  'LOGGING_CONFIG'.
```

If I edit `settings.py` and add `LOGGING_CONFIG=None` I get another error about another missing attribute, and so on.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: is it using a virtual environment?

Comment: @lxer: no, it is not

Comment: the rest of your Django app works without virtual env?  Another queston: what happens when you start the script directly? (` python yourscript.py` )

Comment: @lxer: the Django server works perfectly without virtualenv. The errors I posted are from when running my script directly.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try this

```
import sys, os, django
sys.path.append("/path/to/store") #here store is root folder(means parent).
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "store.settings")
django.setup()

from store_app.models import MyModel
```

This script you can use anywhere in your system.

Comment: Great! Note I needed to use `"store.store.settings"` for it to work.

Comment: If file is nearby manage.py, path to append  sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

Comment: I had `django.urls.reverse()` call in my script, and one of my `urls.py`'s had `reverse()` calls as well. Thus, my `reverse()` call led to loading `urls.py`'s, which in effect made another "recursive" call to `reverse()`. That triggered [`NoReverseMatch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917987/django-1-9-to-1-10-raises-noreversematch-uen-gb-is-not-a-registered-namespace) exception. I dealt with it by doing `from django.core import checks; checks.run_checks()` before doing reverse match. Although there might be a better way.

Comment: `sys.path.append` is supposedly needed when you invoke the script not from the project root.

Comment: what if it's inside a file that gets called multiple times? can I run django.setup() once and it will stay global?

Comment: if someone uses this answer and uses Path to get path to file like this:`BASE_DIR = Path('').resolve().parent`
i had to convert to string or else it wouldn't find the model `sys.path.append(str(BASE_DIR))`

Comment: ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package @António Caeiro

Answer (score 15):

This sounds like a great use case for [Django Management commands.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) which has the added bonus you can run it scheduled from cron, direct from the commandline, or call from inside django.  This gives the script full access to the same settings and environment variables as your main project.

If you move this into an appropriate directory - using store here as an example, not a suggestion, it should work.

```
store 
    management 
    __init__.py
        commands
        __init__.py 
        otherscript.py
```

Answer (score 3):

Django standalone script.

- Place it in the same directory as manage.py file
- Rename PROJECT_NAME to your project's name

```
import os

PROJECT_NAME = 'ENTER YOUR PROJECT NAME HERE'

def main():
    # import statemts
    # from app.models import Author,Category,Book
    
    # code logic - anything you want
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '%s.settings' % PROJECT_NAME)
    import django
    django.setup()
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the `django-extensions` package to be most useful. You can find it [here](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions)

After installation and adding it to the installed apps, all you need to do is to create a directory called `scripts`, create a file and run it by `python manage.py runscript file_name`

Just remember that the file must have an entry point. That entry point is a method called `run` which has to be present and will run once you run `python manage.py runscript file_name` in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

try to import from `store_app.models` - as the surrounding `store` folder is not a python module and should not be used when importing.

```
import django
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(DEBUG=True)
django.setup()

from store_app.models import MyModel
```

update: i just noticed that you put that script next to your project folder - you should move it inside for this to work.

Comment: Can't my_script be in a different package?

Comment: it can, but it depends on your path - a django project is usually not in the path, therefore i adviced you to move it. nevertheless - if you must not run besides django, you should go the way @Withnail mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
>>from store.store_app.apps import StoreAppConfig<<
```

This line can be deleted if "other_script.py" moves to the "store" folder & "settings.py" file inserts "other_script" name in "instaled_apps".
Don't add "other_cript" to "instaled_apps" & change it to:

```
>>from store import settings
settings.configure(settings, DEBUG=True)
django.setup()<<
```

and in the end I think:

```
>>from store.store_app.models import MyModel<<
```

change this to:

```
>>from store_app.models import MyModel<<
```