# Django 1.9 to 1.10 raises NoReverseMatch: u'en-gb' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I am trying to update my 1.9 application to 1.10 and I am getting the following error on running all my unit tests:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/…/tests/views/test_configurator.py", line 261, in test_view_configurator_post
    args=[self.configurator.id]),   File "/home/…/.virtualenvs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse
    raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key) NoReverseMatch: 'en-gb' is not a registered namespace
```

My `setting.py` file contains the following:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: NoReverseMatch error has to do with urls  so check your url patterns

Comment: Show the full traceback

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: Sure but there's not much more to see there.

Comment: how about `test_view_configurator_post`? That's where your error is coming from

Comment: @MosenKoledoye No it is not.  It just happened to be the test I run.  All the test failed with the same error...

Comment: @Sardathrion did you found what was causing this error? If so, could you update the thread? Thanks.

Comment: No,  this is still an issue...

Comment: @Léo: The problem is now solved but the solution is kinda weird.

Comment: Thanks @Sardathrion, definitely weird indeed. I've checked the 1.10.4...1.10.5 diff and didn't saw what could resolve the issue...

Comment: @Sardathrion occured today with 1.10.6. Don't know why 1.10.5 make that working for you, but in my case, I figured out that some `url(...)` were missing on some external app patterns. Wrapping patterns with them fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated to django 1.10.5 and the problem went away.

Go figure!

Answer (score 15):

I encountered this as well, and I narrowed down the cause. I think it's a regression in Django, but I don't have time to write up a full bug report. Here's what I know.

Django waits until the first call to `django.urls.reverse` to populate all the namespaces to a cached `dict`.

There's been some changes to that population procedure recently. 
They added [a `populating` flag that is set to True when you start populating](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.7/django/urls/resolvers.py#L191), and is shared across calls to `reverse`. If the population process happens to make a call to `django.urls.reverse`, the flag will prevent infinite recursion.

The population process involves importing URL patterns - the `urls.py` files you have in your apps. If anything during that import process raises an exception, e.g. an undefined name at the top-level of a module in my case, the population algorithm doesn't catch that, and just stops outright, and *leaves the populating flag to True*. That error, at least for me, was propagated to the top level and I saw it in test runner output.

All subsequent calls to `django.urls.reverse` raise a `NoReverseMatch` error for the `en-us` namespace. Following the code, this is because at the start of the population procedure, if the `populating` flag is truthy, the process just returns and returns the cached namespace dict, which is empty, causing a KeyError for `en-us`, causing a `NoReverseMatch` for `en-us`.

**You should look at the errors that occurred before the first `NoReverseMatch` to find your culprit.** For more info, I think [this is the commit that introduced the regression](https://github.com/django/django/commit/31a789f646d0d9af3e8464f2f9a06aa018df5f90). It has a link to the Django issue it fixed. I think the fix would be to set the `populating` flag to False in case of an exception, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me solve the issue on Django 1.10.7 :)

Comment: Thanks. For me the issue was a malformed urlpatterns definition and this let me to discover the source of the error.

Comment: I had this error under pretty particular conditions. I wrote a standalone script that loads [django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39724171/52499). There I did a reverse match, and one of my `urls.py` also had `reverse()` calls. The second (the one down the stack) `reverse()` call failed with this error. I remedied it by doing `from django.core import checks; checks.run_checks()` before doing reverse match. I'm running `django-2.0.2`.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue on django 1.11.16 -- I was able to alleviate the error by wrapping the 'for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):' with a try / except that sets populating to false on exception. How can i narrow down the actuall problem? My exception says; 'The included URLconf 'portal.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.'  -- https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/urls/resolvers.py#L347

Comment: Nice research, thanks. In my case it was wrong version of DRF that could not support `@detail_route(url_name=...)` and tests failed.

Answer (score 4):

Run [django system check command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#check) it may show the underlying problem:

```
python manage.py check
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your base `urls.py` has an included `urls.py` that has a $ sign mistakenly put into it. This will cause issues with the urlresolvers. Scan your included urls and make sure that there are no dollar signs in them.

Another thing to look out for is if you have any views that throw exceptions in any of your urls.

Comment: An update to Django 1.10.5 has fixed the problem. No idea if your solution would have worked. In any case, thanks for taking the time to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Tommi Kaikkonen's answer, one cause of urls.py evaluation failing might be due to a heavy queryset failing on production in a non-reproducible fashion due to heavy load on the server/db.

The easiest way to find the root cause is to set a breakpoint on [core queryset evaluation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8208381ba6a3d1613bb746617062ccf1a6a28591/django/db/models/query.py#L280) function(s) and do a django runserver in debug mode, anywhere that it triggers, you should re-write the code to make it lazily evalute and optimize the queryset as well if that's a possilibity.

Answer (score -1):

Your `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting is set to `en_gb`. Notice the underscore character. It should be `en-gb`.

Comment: Ah, sorry that was a typo… Makes no difference.