# Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-settings

I'm making a `populate.py` script to transfer data from a `mysql` database to a `django mysqlite` database.

I keep getting this error when I run my `populate.py` script:

```
Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured.
You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

So what I found from my researches was that I had to add `settings.configure()`, so I did that but still getting the error and have no clue anymore what it could be.

This is what I import:

```
import django
import time
import datetime
import os
from mysql.connector import connection
from django.conf import settings
from user import models
from techportal import models

settings.configure()
django.setup()
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'itdb.settings')
```

I've made this function to transfer the data:

```
# Insert all technologies
def technologies():
    current = con_mysql.cursor()
    current_query = ("SELECT technology_id title, description, company_id, author, contactor, publish_date, edit_date, is_hidden, visible FROM technologies")
    current.execute(current_query)

    for (technology_id, title, description, company_id, author, contactor, publish_date, edit_date, is_hidden, visible) in current:
        # Converts datetime to (int)unixtimestamp
        if (publish_date == "0000-00-00 00:00:00"):
            publish_date = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)),
                                                                   "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
        else:
            publish_date = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(publish_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())

        # Converts datetime to (int)unixtimestamp
        if (edit_date == "0000-00-00 00:00:00"):
            edit_date = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)),
                                                                   "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
        else:
            edit_date = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(edit_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())

        mdl, succeeded = models.PortalTechnology.objects.get_or_create(
            author_id=author,
            basetech_id=technology_id,
            is_hidden=is_hidden,
            visible=visible
        )
        mdl.save()

        mdl, succeeded = models.Technology.objects.get_or_create(
            name=title,
            long_description=description,
            created_on=publish_date,
            supplier_id=company_id
        )
        mdl.save()

    current.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26875729/9225671) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39724171/9225671) you need to first set the env variable and then call `django.setup()`:

File **your_script.py**:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")
import django
django.setup()

# here goes the rest of your script ...
import time
import datetime
from mysql.connector import connection
from user import models
from techportal import models

def technologies():
    ...
```

This is necessary since django 1.7 (see [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#standalone-scripts)).

And `settings.configure()` should not be necessary this way.