# from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Tags: python, django, web

I know that this question had been asked and answered already, but the solutions I saw so far are not solving the problem. I am trying to run the following command in python to authenticate users who log in a website I am currently building.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
"C:\Users\<user>\Documents\GitHub\MegaPortal\BackEnd\BackEnd\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

What is weird is that this command gives an error when I run on Atom, but when I run using Django's shell, it does not give any error. I have already tried putting in my settings.py file the following command

```
import django
django.setup()
```

but still nothing.

Any help is highly appreciated.

EDIT: I am running the code from system python not a virtualenv. The code is not on GitHub yet. The Django version is 2.0.2.  My code is:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = authenticate(username='john', password='secret')
if user is not None:
#  redirect to personal page
else:
  print(' ERROR pasword or username is not correct')
```

Comment: Are you running that from system python rather than a virtualenv? Is that project public on Github? What version of django are you using?

Comment: You haven't included enough code in your question to reproduce the issue so it's difficult to help. Putting `django.setup()` in your settings is incorrect - where did you read that it would help?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. That is my first post in here. I have edited the original question to answer your questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723310/django-standalone-script

Think that will help

Answer (score 0):

start cmd in your project's directory and type
cd to main directory of project(where the "manage.py" file is)

then, type

```
python manage.py shell
```

now you'll be inside python interpreter
now import django using:

```
import django
```

them import User using this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

now take whatever actions you want.

Hope this helps