# Django: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, django-models

Strange error, think I must be missing something obvious. I've created a services.py file in my app which will populate my database when the file is run. So it isn't run every time the server boots/queries the file I've added:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import ...
    from models import Authority, Rating

    <logic to populate database>
```

However, when I run the file, Django is throwing the exception:

django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Am I running this file from the wrong place? Would it be better suited to my models file? If so, how do I stop it running every time the server boots?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723310/django-standalone-script

Comment: you should use fixtures to load some data `./manage.py loaddata my_fixture.yaml` or you can run custom python script manualy with `./manage.py shell < my_python.py`

Comment: ...or write a management command as it is intended.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Indeed it seems management commands is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just moved the script over. Works perfectly. Much appreciated!