# Django Error: ImproperlyConfigured / define the environment variable / call settings.configure()

Tags: python, django

I have the following model:

```
class my_model(models.Model):
    item_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=100)
    item_array = ArrayField(models.FloatField())
```

When I try:

```
df = pd.read_pickle('df.pkl')

db = my_model()

for item in df.columns:
    db.item_id = item
    db.item_array = df[item]

db.save()
```

I get the following error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, 
but settings are not configured. You must either define the 
environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call 
settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

What could I do to fix this?

Comment: Django models can't access via normal scripts, if you wanted to, you need to follow certain procedures

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Standalone Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723310/django-standalone-script)

Comment: @Arakkal I'll try the suggestion.. in the meantime, what is the correct way to upload data into the database?

Comment: Use django-orm for that