# Django Standalone Script in Django 4.1

Tags: python, django, import, django-4.1

I am trying to run a standalone script in django 4.1. I have the setup as suggested in this post at the top of my file:

[Django Standalone Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723310/django-standalone-script)

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "path_to_settings.settings")
import django
django.setup()
```

However, on the 4th line, I get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sport_api'`

This is my `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # applications
    'sport_api',
    'sport_bet',

    # library
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]
```

How do I get around this error?

Update:

[image: Directory Structure]

Comment: It's inside sport_api. Can it not be there?

Comment: With some effort, it can. See my answer.

Comment: Any reason not to use a management command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move the script to the `manage.py` layer. That's the only thing that got this to work for me.

Answer (score 5):

With just that snippet, your script should be in the same directory as manage.py.

Otherwise, if you're nesting it in `Backend\sportivo\sport_api`, then you need:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import sys
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR.as_posix())
# ...
```

Depending on how nested it is, just adjust `BASE_DIR` with `.parent` as needed.

It's best to use [custom management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) for standalone scripts though.

Comment: I would like to use custom management commands but I need to put it in a lambda function and as far as I know, that's not supported.

Comment: I tried this several different ways and it didn't work no matter how many `.parent` I put in.

Comment: Try `sys.path.append(str(BASE_DIR))` instead of `BASE_DIR.as_posix()`.

Answer (score 0):

> Actual module not found as you didn't give the right path

- Try this `sportivo.sport_api` same for another.
- Check this for best understanding [out](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/module-not-found-error-in-python-solved/)

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: you add folder sportivo to your path in project root ?