# from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand, CommandError ImportError: cannot import name 'NoArgsCommand'

Tags: python, django

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prototypes.py", line 39, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/leo/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/leo/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/leo/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.5/site-package/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/leo/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/leo/Desktop/prototypes/sitebuilder/management/commands/build.py", line 42, in handle
call_command('compress',interactive=False,force=True)
File "/home/leo/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 113, in call_command
command = load_command_class(app_name, command_name)
File "/home/leo/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 40, in load_command_class
module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/leo/Desktop/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/compressor/management/commands/compress.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand, CommandError
ImportError: cannot import name 'NoArgsCommand'
```

When I run  python3 prototypes.py build i got this problem. i just want to compressor the css and js file. and this is my setting.

```
import os
import sys
from django.conf import settings


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

settings.configure(
   DEBUG=True,
   SECRET_KEY='plasq@qb+&t-@=x56@=ss=+y-4kp*hj1wy5p!+$cinzhnd+erb',
   ROOT_URLCONF='sitebuilder.urls',
   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=(),
   INSTALLED_APPS=(
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
       'sitebuilder',
       'compressor',
    ),

TEMPLATES=(
    {
        'BACKEND':'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS':[],
        'APP_DIRS':True,
    },
),
STATIC_URL='/static/',
SITE_PAGES_DIRECTORY=os.path.join( BASE_DIR,'pages'),
SITE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=os.path.join( BASE_DIR,'_build'),

STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join( BASE_DIR,'_build','static'),
STATICFILES_FINDERS=(
                     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
                     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
                     'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
                     )
    )
if __name__=="__main__":
     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I followed the book "Lightweight Django".

Comment: This question can be improved. Please provide some context around the issue you are encountering and summarize what your code is intended to do. Also, it is very important you include your own research into the problem including what you believe may be the problem and the steps you have taken to attempt a fix. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 18):

According to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.8/#django-core-management-noargscommand), the class `NoArgsCommand` is now deprecated and will be removed from Django 1.10. Use `BaseCommand` instead, which takes no arguments by default.

Here is what you can do (I commented out the old way for your reference):

```
#from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
    
    #class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    class Command(BaseCommand):
    
        #def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        def handle(self, *args, **options):
        ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, its working in my case.

```
try:
    from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand as BaseCommand
except ImportError:
    from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    """ 
    ABC
    def
    """
```

Then write your class definition with your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its working in my case.

```
pip install -U django-extensions
```

NoArgsCommand was deprecated. Just update the library